# how to get the Golang function pointer and the external program can call this function by the pointer?

Tags: go, webassembly, wasmtime, dfinity

First call the update function, and then call an asynchronous function ic0.Call_new. Pass the pointer address of the callback function ic.Call_new as a parameter. The host env will call the callback through the pointer address. the running environment of the code is on the wasm virtual machine

```
type State struct {
    value uint16
}

var state State = State{
    value: 0,
}


func update() {
   
    callbackPtr := int32(uintptr(reflect.ValueOf(callback).Pointer()))
    callId := [20]byte{68, 73, 68, 76, 1, 110, 104, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
    method := [16]byte{101, 99, 100, 115, 97, 95, 112, 117, 98, 108, 105, 99, 95, 107, 101, 121}
    statePtr := int32(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&state)))
    ic0.Call_new(
        int32(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&callId))),
        20,
        int32(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&method))),
        16,
        callbackPtr,
        statePtr,
        callbackPtr,
        statePtr,
    )
}



func callback(statePtr int32) {
    var tmpState *State = (*State)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(statePtr)))
    tmpState.value = 3
}
```

1. In the wasm environment, is this really the correct way to obtain the callback function pointer?
2. the error info: function invocation does not match its signature, error code None

Comment: You can't! read the documentation about [What is pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))